# Recycle IIS App Pool from a different server using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, application-pool

Is it possible to recycle an IIS APP Pool using c# from a different server?

I can recycle the IIS App Pool if the App is inside the server but I want to trigger the recycle app pool from a different server.

Example:

- Server A: App which has a button that connects to Server B then executes a Recycle App Pool.
- Server B: Server that contains the main app that needs to be recycled after the button was pressed in Server A.

Comment: Yes, just wire the API

Comment: @Martheen, can you send me a basic snippet and I'll do the rest. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/ has been there for years.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the link. This is a big help.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote?view=iis-dotnet) that provides the remote connection to a different server which uses ServerManager.OpenRemote()

```
ServerManager.OpenRemote("<server name or IP address>")
```